# How to delete duplicated rows with several files?

Tags: perl, bash, awk, unix

I have 7 files with the following names in different directories and subdirectories

```
tag0.txt, tag1.txt, tag2.txt, tag3.txt, tag01.txt, tag02.txt and tag03.txt
```

Some of these files have duplicated rows. How can I delete the `duplicated rows`? Note that the rows in each file are not sorted and the length of each file range from 500 to 1000 rows.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean duplicated within each file, or duplicated across multiple files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove dupes on a *per-file basis*, the following doesn't require sorted files and thus doesn't mess with the order of the lines:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' infile > outfile
```

Since your files seem to be in different directories it's probably easiest to just run that command manually 7 times. If you really want to though you can loop it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 ... /path/to/file7; do
    awk '!a[$0]++' "$file" > "$file".new && \
    mv "$file".new "$file"
done
```

Comment: Sorry, I like to keep the same names. Do we need to rename them afterwards?

Comment: @Tony yes, you need to rename them. I just updated my while-loop to do this for you.  I would first backup your 7 files just in case something doesn't go right.

Comment: +1 You can do `awk ... && mv ...` so the `mv` is contingent on the success of the AWK command.

Answer (score 1):

use `sort` and `uniq` command which are unix utilities

```
cat "your files" | sort | uniq
```

Comment: -1 This would not work for the above requirement, there is no removal of rows from the files.

Comment: @VCBuddy nothing prevent you from redirecting the output to an actual file (but of course not the source one )

Comment: -1: seems the question is to work on each file in turn, not create a single file.

Comment: @Dennis +1, Somebody should make a rage comic for this =)

Answer (score 1):

Attention, does change the file "directly" ( in-place edit ).

```
perl -i -ne 'print if not $seen{$ARGV}{$_}++' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

bash 4.0++

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/tag*.txt
do
    sort $file|uniq > t && mv t $file
done
```

Comment: is `sort|uniq` different from `sort -u`? (real question, not sarcasm)

Comment: @glenn AFAIK, no, there is no difference if you're not using any of `uniq`'s options.

Comment: Unfortunately, the globstar isn't going to do much here because his 'tag' files are not only in different subdirs, but in different root dirs as well.

Comment: @SiegeX, if he knows where those root directories are, its only a matter of specifying them with the for loop. the globstar is just like recursive find , so think its still useful.

Comment: @glenn. yes i could have used sort -u as well. it has no difference with uniq since I don't think OP needs to make use of uniq features.